# Does the EDGE mobile network function independently of an antenna?

Tags: internet

I have an old iPhone 4 with a faulty antenna. The Wi-Fi doesn't work and neither does the 3G network, despite the fact that I have plenty of mobile data, but [EDGE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enhanced_Data_Rates_for_GSM_Evolution) still seems to work - the icon shows at the top when mobile data is enabled, and it loads websites load about as fast as can be expected of it.

Does this mean that EDGE functions independently of an antenna? If so, how exactly does it function?

Comment: The problem you are presuming here is that the “faulty antenna” is negatively affecting the 3G antenna and Wi-Fi.m Could be a combination of things. Besides, how do you know the antenna is broken? You are 100% positive of that.

Comment: @JakeGould Why it would be a flawed assumption to assume that a component solely responsible for a given function is also responsible for lack of that function when said component is faulty? That's literally the most logical assumption. And the faulty antenna was confirmed by a repair shop.

Comment: Well, I think your detective work proves us both correct: Two antennas means that if one breaks and the other doesn’t then there you go. Nice job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the time to do some digging, and it seems that EDGE does indeed function independently of the antenna responsible for WiFi, at least as far as the iPhone 4 is concerned.

The iPhone 4 and its variants have two antennas, both of them [external](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_4#Design). This was the first iPhone in which Apple had introduced external antennas, and did so in the form of a long metallic band around the phone's edge, broken up by non-conductive strips<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

As illustrated below, the device's leftmost antenna is responsible for Bluetooth, WiFi and GPS operations, and the rightmost one responsible for UMTS and GSM<sup>2</sup>:

[image]

EDGE is short for Enhanced Data Rates for GSM, and is a technology based on the GSM standard. This means that EDGE uses an entirely separate antenna to the one utilised by the phone's WiFi and Bluetooth capabilities, and that it would therefore be entirely plausible for the phone's WiFi antenna to be damaged beyond use while its EDGE antenna remained functional.

---

1. Incidentally, this decision was a [source of major contention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_4#Antenna) at the time of the phone's release, as covering one of these non-conductive strips with your fingers would bridge the two antennas together and result in [loss of signal and dropped calls](https://www.anandtech.com/show/3794/the-iphone-4-review/2) due to attenuation.

   At the time, Apple [responded](https://www.engadget.com/2010/06/24/apple-responds-over-iphone-4-reception-issues-youre-holding-th/) first by telling affected customers they were holding their phones wrong, and then by releasing "bumpers" that would cover the antennas to physically prevent them being touched. The iPhone 4's antenna design hasn't been implemented [in any iPhone since](https://www.lifewire.com/iphone-4-antenna-problems-explained-2000280).
2. Note that these details only apply to the GSM version of the phone; the CDMA version differs slightly, and also introduces four non-metallic strips to the antenna band instead of the GSM equivalent's two.

Comment: Your question and answer are both off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Slower/simpler modulation schemes and certain frequency ranges are more tolerant of bad conditions and interference.  This is true whether we are talking about cellular technology, WiFi, or even any type of wired communication.

Cable modems, for example, if I have this right, create channels on various frequency ranges to talk from your modem to the cable company head end.  A wiring problem can interfere with higher frequency channels but not lower frequency ones - so your connection will slow down but not go out completely.  So a suboptimal antenna may work fine for slower/simpler standards like EDGE but not others.  Could be wrong, I don't know the details of EDGE or how it works.

Comment: EDGE is kind of "2 and a bit G". It really shouldn't be fast enough to load web pages "as fast as can be expected"... well, unless the 'expected' part was "about 5 minutes" for anything more complex than a mobile data page without imagery.

Comment: @Tetsujin "As expected" was per my own expectations - it took it about a minute to load the Google homepage using Safari.

Comment: Please do not answer off-topic questions.